# Is the $2y$ bcrypt hash version supported by Spring 5 Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, bcrypt, jbcrypt

I searched through the Documentation for Spring 5 Security but I could not find a reference to the BCrypt `$2y$` version prefix anywhere.

When looking through the source code, though, I found one reference in the [Javadoc of the `PasswordEncoder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java):

> can optionally supply a "version" ($2a, $2b, $2y)

Can anyone give me some consensus? Is it possible to use the `$2y$` bcrypt version prefix when using Spring 5 Security?

Comment: Have you tried it? The link you've provided is for spring-security (which you're asking for) so I can't think of a reason why it wouldn't work.

Comment: I can try, but if this works then why is it nowhere included in the Spring documentation? This is a big improvement, as the $2y$ version prefix has been a major hassle in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what version you're using, [the commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/388a7b62b906bd56deadb7ca45248fa1a63bdf12) in which this feature introduced was on Oct 18, 2018. It has the tag `5.2.0.M1` which means that's the release this commit will be introduced in, [the official docs of that version now specify this feature exists](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.2.0.M1/api/):

> Implementation of PasswordEncoder that uses the BCrypt strong hashing
>   function. Clients can optionally supply a "version" ($2a, $2b, $2y)
>   and a "strength" (a.k.a. log rounds in BCrypt) and a SecureRandom
>   instance. The larger the strength parameter the more work will have to
>   be done (exponentially) to hash the passwords. The default value is
>   10.

Before version `5.2.0.M1` this feature did not exist, there's no official release yet of this version, only snapshots (`5.2.0.M1` was released on Jan 16, 2019).

This version (or newer) is what you'll have to use if you want to use this feature, until an official release is made.